# How can I create a FileSystem to a jar inside another jar

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to use NIO FileSystem to access a jar inside another jar.
Call the outside jar my-outer.jar and the inner my-inner.jar
(Using Java 8 and Windows 7 but I think that is not the issue)

I am using the following code

```
    String zipfilePath = "c:/testfs/my-outer.jar!/my-inner.jar";
    Path path = Paths.get(zipfilePath);
    try(ZipFileSystem zipfs = (ZipFileSystem) FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null))
    { ...  }
```

but I am getting the exception below when trying to create that newFileSystem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: C:\testfs\my-outer.jar!\my-inner.jar
```

Note that if I just use the outer jar as the FileSystem, that works perfectly fine and I can read and write files from it beautifully. It's just when I try to reach into the inner archive that the troubles begin.

Doesn't FileSystem support the JarURLConnection notation?

Comment: From looking to decompiled sources of ZipFileSystem it seems that it supports only "real" files. For nested ZIP (jar) archives you'll need to use "low-level" java.util.zip package (or extract inner arcive to the disk, though I wouldn't call that a good solution).

Comment: Not a good idea. Even a one-level JAR filesystem is going to perform very poorly.

Answer (score 2):

As said by vbezhenear and as experimented by myself the JarURLConnection notation in the form `c:/testfs/my-outer.jar!/my-inner.jar` seems not implemented by the factory method `FileSystems.newFileSystem(Path path, ClassLoader loader)`.

But you can still access the inner jar like this:

```
Path outerPath = Paths.get("c:/testfs/my-outer.jar");
try (FileSystem outerFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(outerPath, null)) {
    Path innerPath = outerFS.getPath("/my-inner.jar");
    try (FileSystem innerFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(innerPath, null)) {
       ...
    }
}
```

--UPDATE--

If you try to use an `URI` instead of a `Path` you can create a `ZipFileSystem` like this

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/home/orto/stackoverflow/outer.jar!/inner.jar");
Map<String,String> env = Collections.emptyMap();
try(ZipFileSystem zipfs = (ZipFileSystem)FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri,env))
{...}
```

But no luck you get access to the `outer.jar` and not the `inner.jar`

If you look at the source code of `JarFileSystemProvider` you see

```
@Override
protected Path uriToPath(URI uri) {
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    if ((scheme == null) || !scheme.equalsIgnoreCase(getScheme())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI scheme is not '" + getScheme() + "'");
    }
    try {
        String uristr = uri.toString();
        int end = uristr.indexOf("!/");
        uristr = uristr.substring(4, (end == -1) ? uristr.length() : end);
        uri = new URI(uristr);
        return Paths.get(new URI("file", uri.getHost(), uri.getPath(), null))
                    .toAbsolutePath();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e); //never thrown
    }
}
```

The path is cut up before the first `"!"`. So there is no way to directly create a file system on the inside jar from the `newFileSystem` method.

Comment: I like your first answer. I didn't understand if your "update" was giving another answer or just explaining my question

Comment: The "update" is just there to show that there is (yet) no implementation of the feature you were looking for. (Creating a ZipFileSystem located with JarURLConnection notation)

Comment: This (no longer? as at 8u74) seems to work as `FileSystems.newFileSystem(innerPath, null)` throws `ProviderNotFoundException` because `ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem()` bails out if `path.getFileSystem() != FileSystems.getDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

A way late answer, but the title of the problem is how to make a filesystem of a jar contained in another jar.  My solution to this problem was to extract the contained jar to a temporary location and then create a FileSystem using that extracted jar location. If you made any changes to the extracted copy, you'll have to put them back into the jar it came from. I ran into this when I had to extract "classes.jar" from an aar file and copy the content in that jar to another jar. In my case, the extracted copy never gets modified, so that simplifies things.